# MATE Dock Applet shows wrong application icons

Tags: 16.04, mate, applet

I am using MATE Dock Applet v.80 (GTK2) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the Mate desktop. It works fine, but for some programs the wrong application icons appear, which is quite confusing.

For example, the application *TagSpaces* (see: http://www.tagspaces.org) shows the icon of PyChess. When opening the context menu for this application, all entries are labelled with "PyChess". The program TagSpaces is a portable version, so no installation was necessary.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Please list these "some programs" in the question. And specify how did you installed them.

Comment: @N0rbert I have added one application.

Comment: pgAdmin is another program that has losen the icon, now appears "rears" icon